# How many 147 were made in a decider frame

Tags: records, snooker

I am curious to know how many times maximum breaks were scored in a decider frame. I remember one from Ronnie but don't remember the opponent.

Were there any more records like this?

Answer (score 1):

This information can be obtained from the [maximum break](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_break) page on Wikipedia. The section *"match-winning maximum breaks"* lists 18 breaks in total and 5 of them are in deciding frames.

Here are the 147s made in deciding frames:

> - [Stephen Hendry - 1997 Charity Challenge, Final](https://youtu.be/eBKH4JvJQFE)
> - Ronnie O'Sullivan - 2007 UK Championship, Semi-final
> - Mark Davis - 2017 Championship League, Group final
> - Mark Davis - 2017 Championship League, Winners' Group
> - Martin Gould - 2018 Championship League, Group 6

In the Championship League, almost 200 matches are played and each match is won by the best of 5 frames. Therefore it is very probable to see a 147 in a deciding frame.

We should also note that Ronnie O'Sullivan is the only player who has such a break in a ranking tournament. On top of that it's a UK semi-final.